# Migrate SVN to Git, non-standard layout

Tags: git, svn, migration, version-control

I am trying to migrate our work SVN repository to Git. I am using [the following library](https://github.com/nirvdrum/svn2git) to assist with building the git-svn command.

The problem is our SVN repo is set out like so:

```
svn root/
    archive/
        archived_branch_1
        archived_branch_2
        ...
    some_branch
    another_branch
    some_other_branch
    again_another_branch
    ...
```

We have no trunk and no tags. The root just contains branches. There is also a archive directory (possibly acting like a branch) which contains old branches.

They want to keep the full history is possible. I am able to migrate one branch at a time but the history only goes as far back as when the branch was created but in reality the branch was created in SVN by branching off a previous release so it should contain the full history.

If I run the `svn2git` command manually specifying the branches in the root directory and also specify the ones in the archive directory (there are a lot) then the command is over 200 characters long and ran from 3pm yesterday to 10am this morning where I stopped it.

Any suggestions how I can migrate this non-standard layout to git with full history on each branch further back than when it was created?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/79165/8928481

Comment: I have seen similar posts but the issue the non-standard layout and forcing is to get branches from the root only.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/573619/960558 + one more svn2git https://github.com/iteman/svn2git/tree/master + https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn#_configuration (read below "It is also possible to fetch a subset of branches or tags by using a comma-separated list of names within braces..." part of data)